# Login as root in Ajaxterm

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, bash, terminal

I am trying to use `Ajaxterm` and I remember that when I used it for the first time about a year ago, there was something about logging in as root.

Can anyone tell me how to enable root login or point me to a guide? Many different google searches have returned no results.

P.S. My question is ***NOT*** whether or not I *should* login as root, but *how* to login as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have logged in as a non-root user you can just `su` to the root user